# oracle select where not exists in second select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these ID and I always get them in this format:

> 538693 , 538693 , 541616 , 541616 , 541616 , 541620 , 541116 , 541116
>   , 538639 , 538639 , 538720 , 538720 , 538720 , 541608 , 541608 ,
>   541608 , 538675 , 538675 , 538675 , 538675

then I do query which returns me few of them, for example returns me last 3 ID .
Now I need to select remaining ID from the first record set without last 3.

This is just sample, i have more then 200 rows of this ID..

Comment: sample data and required result would help. Also, show us your work that you have tried so far.

Comment: select 538693 , 538693 , 541616 , 541616 , 541616 , 541620 , 541116 , 541116 , 538639 , 538639 , 538720 , 538720 , 538720 , 541608 , 541608 , 541608 , 538675 , 538675 , 538675 , 538675 
from dual
where  not exists (select 538675 ,538675 , 538675 from dual);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example which might give you an idea. Have a look.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- a long list of (duplicate?) IDs
  3  all_ids (col) as
  4    (select '538693 , 538693 , 541616 , 541616 , 541616 , 541620 , 541116 , 541116 , 538639 , 538639' from dual
  5    ),
  6  -- that's what you get from your query
  7  do_query (col) as
  8    (select '541116 , 538639 , 538639' from dual
  9    ),
 10  -- split ALL_IDs to rows
 11  all_1 as
 12    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^ , ]+', 1, level) col
 13     from all_ids
 14     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
 15    ),
 16  -- split IDs from DO_QUERY to rows as well
 17  do_1 as
 18    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^ , ]+', 1, level) col
 19     from do_query
 20     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
 21    ),
 22  -- MINUS set operator will return IDs from ALL_IDS that aren't in DO_QUERY IDs
 23  minus_me as
 24    (select col From all_1
 25     minus
 26     select col from do_1
 27    )
 28  -- finally, compose the remaining **unique** IDs back
 29  select listagg(col, ' , ') within group (order by col) result
 30  from minus_me;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
538693 , 541616 , 541620

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler using `xmltable` for numbers

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT to_number(column_value) AS n
    FROM XMLTABLE('538693 , 538693 , 541616 , 541616 , 541616 , 541620 , 541116 ,
                   541116 , 538639 , 538639 , 538720 , 538720 , 538720 , 541608 , 
                   541608 , 541608 , 538675 , 538675 , 538675 , 538675')
    ) o
WHERE n NOT IN (
     select to_number(column_value) 
  FROM xmltable(
        '538675
        ,538675
        ,538675')
        );
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/843)

Answer (score 0):

I dont have oracle to try out, but probably this would work.

Eg. If you have IDs 1,2,3...10, below query will return 1,2,3,..7

```
SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE ROWNUM < 3)
```

Not sure about syntax, just try out the logic :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution w/out converting output to string. See if this is acceptable in your case. This will convert your rows to columns. Then it is easy to eliminate the last 3 rows:

```
select distinct column_value from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5));
```

Comment: @civesuas_sine - Here's the example. Replace emp table with your table name to select your values. See MichaelS Aug 23 example at:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/1120647